# How to reduce response time of the web page to minimum in django?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-media

Currently my network speed is about 1.5s per page if there are images in that page, If i move to different pages with image, audio and video file in it then loading of page takes around 2s to 2.5s. What i want to know is if there is a way to bring that loading time to minimum.

I am using Django, and Django-templates here to create such web application.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about images, audio and video, first I will play with the size and quality of the image, make some tests. For the audio and video you might want to use the attribute **preload="none"**. This from the template. Another option is to upload image/audio/video by scroll, or paging. It is not a good practice to send all together. i.e: show 10/15 multimedia per page

From the view check the queries you are executing and the data structures you are using (memory consume is important, avoid huge lists and jsons). The same goes for the custom filters, if applicable.